# How angular2 get query-param like this "sort=field1,asc&sort=field2,desc&sort=field3,asc"

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, query-string

I use angular2

if the url is like this :

> url?sort=field1,asc&sort=field2,desc

I use

```
getParams() {
    if (this.route.snapshot.queryParams) {
     console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams)  

     // it print like this :  sort: "[object Object]"

     console.log(typeof this.route.snapshot.queryParams['sort']);  // is string
    }
}
```

How to get "field1,asc" and "field2,desc" form  **sort: "[object Object]"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params are always only strings. There's no way around that. So when you try to pass an object as the param value, it will just call `Object.toString` on the object, which defaults to `[object Object]`. If you have a class, you can override the `toString`. Maybe something like

```
class Sort {
  constructor(public field: string, public order: string) {}

  static parse(value: string): Sort {
    const split = value.split(',');
    return new Sort(split[0], split[1]);
  }

  toString() {
    return `${this.field},${this.order}`;
  }
}
```

Then when you add the query params just do

```
this.router.navigate(['...'], { queryParams: { sort: new Sort('field1', 'desc') }});
```

Angular will call the `toString` on the `Sort` instance when creating the query params. Then on the receiving side, just call `Sort.parse(value)`.